# is there an option to create document in symfony doctrine odm, using command line?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm

Is there any way that i can create documents in Symfony using command line just like creating an entity in case of orm (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Creating entities in Doctrine ORM is deprecated and will be removed with the next major version. It seems that Doctrine ODM does not provide that feature currently, as can can be checked when looking at the [available commands](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/tree/master/Command) on GitHub.

You might be able to adapt [MakeEntity](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Maker/MakeEntity.php) from the MakerBundle for documents, if you feel like contributing such a feature to the community.

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you please help me since i am new to MongoDB, is there any way (other than creating manually)  to create documents files with getters and setters in Symfony doctrine option?.

Comment: I remember reading in some github issues from doctrineODMBundle that the CLI Document generation won't get any support in the future. (I took the time to search for the issue : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/498#issuecomment-434338426). So actually you can't automatically generate Document, but it's not that difficult to create them manually (getters/setters can be auto generated in any modern IDE).